# Как сделать переход из одного фрагмента в другой с помощью кнопки на экране?(без TabLayout)

Tags: java, android

Как сделать переход из одного фрагмента в другой с помощью кнопки на экране?(без TabLayout).Если можно,буду благодарен за код.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создать интерфейс

```
public interface IClickListener{

     void onClick();

}
```

Далее во фрагменте

```
private IClickListener mClickListener;

//Some code


@Override

public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {

    super.onAttach(context);

    mClickListener = (IClickListener) context;

 }



Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

    @Override public void onClick(View v) {

    mClickListener.onClick();

});
```

Далее в вашем активити с фрагментом

```
public class Activity implements ILoginListener {

//Some code


@Override

public void onClick() {

    startFragment(yourFragment);

}



private void startFragment(Fragment fragment) {

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);

    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.commit();

    }
}
```

Здесь можно почитать доп информацию
https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/176-urok-106-android-3-fragments-vzaimodejstvie-s-activity.html